# Simple vector question invloving cross product.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the area of the triangle having vertices at $A(1,0,1), B(0,2,3), C(2,1,0)$.
I have found this;

$$\vec{AC} = (1,1,-1)$$
$$\vec{AB} = (-1,2,2)$$

then
$$\frac{||\vec{AC}\times\vec{AB}||}{2}  = \sqrt {26}/2$$

Now, find the length of the altitude from vertex C to side AB;

[image]

excuse the diagram, but I'm assuming I want h.

$$h = \vec{AC} - proj_{\vec{AB}} \vec{AC}$$

But I keep getting the incorrect answer.

Comment: The area is also given by $\frac{AB\cdot h}{2}$

Comment: But I am not given h. Or are you suggesting that I equate that to the area I have found then...

Comment: It is exactly what I am suggesting. You have the area with the cross product and therefore $h=\frac{2\cdot area}{AB}$

Comment: I thought so, that would have saved me quite a lot of time! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, just got it;

I was calculating the wrong projection.

$$\vec{h} = (8,11,-7)/9$$

Then the magnitude of this is what I require